# Display Node Title field in Field group

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I can't find the solution to `print` (display) Drupal's Node Title in a field group? I want my Node Title in the field group (see image).

[image]

In this project I can't use Display Suite. I also can't find a template suggestion for a field group?

How do I manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to install the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module.

Once both *Display Suite* and *Display Suite UI* modules are enabled you must go to the presentation, choose a layout at the bottom and save, then you will have a lot of fields that weren't available before. One of those fields is the node title.

Comment: yes I know DS has this option, but like I described in my question I can't use DS. Because I think DS will mess-up, the already themed and styled site. Is there a way doing it without DS? Or is there nothing to be afraid of using DS and add it to my already styled and themed website?

Comment: It may, or may not, mess this particular content type. But it shouldn't damage any other content type template. I'd do a backup, cross my fingers and try it.